# VB.Net 3.5 Windows - How to get process User Object count

Tags: .net, windows, process, object, count

Can any one please advise me how I can get the current count of "USER Object"s (as shown in task manager) for the current process.

I see how to get the handle count using:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess.HandleCount
```

But our application can reach a USER Object count of 10,000 just by opening 17 instances of a particular form so we would like to try and warn a user that resources are getting low before they reach the limit and the application bombs.

Comment: I'd recommend that you run your app through a profiler, as it may be leaking user objects.

Comment: Hi Helen,

There currently appears to be no leaks as the USER object count returns to where it started when we close the form after opening it. It does not appear to hemorrage USER objects. The form has a lot of usercontrols each with a handle full of .Net controls on it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm thinking of the right kinds of user objects you can do it with the [GetGuiResources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683192%28VS.85%29.aspx) API function. See the pinvoke page for it [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetGuiResources.html) for a C# sample (the second one that sends in 1 as the flag).

Here's a VB translation of the code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<DllImport("User32")> _
Public Shared Function GetGuiResources(ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, ByVal uiFlags As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Public Shared Function GetGuiResourcesUserCount() As Integer
    Return GetGuiResources(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, 1)
End Function
```